# Central Limit Theorem and non-normal Distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, central-limit-theorem

Hopefully a simple question, just trying to solidify some understanding here.

The **Central Limit Theorem** holds that if you take various samples of a finite variance distribution of great enough size (i.e. >= 30), ***the distribution of the sample means will begin to form a normal distribution*** - and therefore has been stated should be useable for parametric testing.

Is this true?

And if so, I'm trying to conceptualize how. If you run an **Independent Samples T Test** between 2 non-normal distributed samples - say.... exponential, the test assumes normality between the 2 sample distributions.

So, in order to not violate the assumption, are you supposed to bootstrap several samples from each sample in order to create normal distribution of sample means, and then do the test on this distribution of means (since they'll be normal)?

Or just run the test between the 2 exponentially distributed samples that you have?

Comment: Take any distribution with finite variance. Generate a random sample from that distribution of size $n$ and take the mean. Repeat this $m$ times. Observe the empirical distribution of these $m$ quantities and compare to a properly scaled Normal distribution. How does the approximation change for different $(n,m)$?

For your second question, the CLT implies that these two independent sample means are each Normal for sufficient $n$. The test requires that the two sample means be Normal, and the CLT takes care of that for you.

Comment: The distribution of sample means become normal once you have sufficient repetitions of size n, correct? So is the test ran on the distribution of sample means themselves (bootstrapped, or several trials), or just the 1 sample of each population (which is non-normal i.e. exponential).

Comment: For CLT, for each data, you take different samples of size n, then for each sample finds the mean, then the distributions of these means will be approximately normal. For the t-test, you should have normal data to hold the test.

Comment: if your distribution is close to normal then, any sample size will be sufficient for CLT. If the shape of your data is far away from normal, then a sufficiently large sample size is needed.

Comment: If your data is not normally distributed and would like to use a t-test, then try to apply a transformation to your data to become normal.